Conditional branches of a 'when' expression in Kotlin
I need to write a Kotlin function that returns a result based on the outcome of a 'when' statement. For a trivial example, lets suppose my code looks like this:
fun combineThings(newThing:String, otherThing:String):String
{
    val thing1 = "abc"
    val thing2 = "def"
    val thing3 = "ghi"
    
    return when {
        newThing.length == 2 -> thing1 + thing2
        newThing.contains("qr") -> thing2 + thing3
        newThing.contains("123") -> thing1 + thing3
        newThing.length == 4 -> thing1 + thing2 + thing3
        else -> otherThing
    }
}

Simple enough. The problem is, I need a way to add more complicated logic. Suppose I wanted some of the branches to be evaluated ONLY when some other condition is true. So going back to the example, lets say I want to add logic to evaluate the second and third branches ONLY if otherThing == "foo". If otherThing != "foo", those branches get skipped and the when statement continues checking the rest of the branches.
In this trivial example, I could simply add an AND statement with the additional logic to each branch. In a real application however, that is going to be time consuming and prone to errors. I'm looking for some way to add a conditional block around the branches that need additional logic.
Is there any way to do what I want using a 'when' statement? If not, is there some other alternative to a bunch of if/else statements?

If you don't want to duplicate your condition with &&s I think the only remaining solution is a nested when block but to utilize it correctly you'd need to reorder your cases so the "combined" ones are last + you'd have multiple "else" cases to return. And if your combined cases are not exclusive it might not even be possible., maybe you have to look for another pattern to solve your problem rather than having a god-switch.

Other option is to use a series of if blocks and put return statements inside them if you don’t want to go to the next condition down. Then you can nest ifs inside these blocks for the more complicated logic.

If you have a complicated conditional logic you can separate it from the when statement and its branches:
val is2And3 = otherThing == "foo" && newThing.contains("qr")
val is1And3 = otherThing == "foo" && newThing.contains("123")

return when {
    newThing.length == 2 -> thing1 + thing2
    is2And3 -> thing2 + thing3
    is1And3 -> thing1 + thing3
    newThing.length == 4 -> thing1 + thing2 + thing3
    else -> otherThing
}

This way you have more freedom defining the conditions, and the when branches are still simple and easy to understand.

That is really clever. Unfortunately I don't think it would scale to situations where there are more than a handful of cases.

It's the other way around: The more complex it is the more important it becomes to extract certain parts to make it more manageable. The first step would be to keep the when clean as shown in my answer. If the extracted logic is still too complex you can always simplify that too, for example by extracting certain parts in separate functions. -- Just having a simple when with tens of branches scales pretty well when each branch is trivial.

Ok, I think I see what you are driving at.
